# Double Click on Edge of Cell Jump (How to Disable?)

Tags: vba, excel

The code takes an active cell and if it is in the appropriate column, and has the value "YES" it runs one of two codes (depending on whether it is a summary or an individual value). This done on 'raw' data that is not in a table or pivot table.

About half the time that I double click on any cell in that sheet it jumps my active cell to either the top or bottom of the range of cells. What is causing this? What can I do to fix it?

This happens on both "YES" and "NO" cells.

Edit: Figured it out. It's an excel shortcut I was not aware of (I don't use the mouse much on excel). Double clicking a cells border jumps you to the top or bottom of that section. Is there a way in VBA to disable this 'feature' for a specific sheet. I can't seem to find any info on Google about it...

Edit 2: Found this: https://superuser.com/questions/610805/disable-navigate-to-end-of-list-when-double-clicking-on-border-of-selected-cell
But I do not want to disable drag and drop in the worksheet AND I want to do it with VBA.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Value <> "YES" Then
       Exit Sub
   Else
      If Target.Column <> 11 Then
          Exit Sub
     Else
Cancel = False
Dim j As String
Dim k As String
Dim i As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set i = Target
    k = i.Offset(0, -7).Value 'First value for filter
         Worksheets("Comments").Activate
        If Worksheets("Comments").AutoFilterMode = True Then
             Worksheets("Comments").AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
If i.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Comments" Then
     j = i.Offset(-1, -9).Value
     Worksheets("Comments").Range("C2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=j

Else
    j = i.Offset(0, -9).Value
    Worksheets("Comments").Range("C2").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=k
    Worksheets("Comments").Range("C2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=j
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Worksheets("Comments").Range("A1").Activate

        End If
        End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me organize your code, it is not very easy to read. Hope this works, I cannot try it right now.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim j As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim i As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cancel = False
    Set i = Target

    If Target.Value <> "YES" and Target.Column <> 11 Then
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.CellDragAndDrop = False 
        k = i.Offset(0, -7).Value 'First value for filter
        Worksheets("Comments").Activate

        If Worksheets("Comments").AutoFilterMode = True Then
             Worksheets("Comments").AutoFilterMode = False
        End If

        If i.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Comments" Then
             j = i.Offset(-1, -9).Value
             Worksheets("Comments").Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=j
        Else
             j = i.Offset(0, -9).Value
             Worksheets("Comments").Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=k
             Worksheets("Comments").Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=j
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Worksheets("Comments").Range("A1").select

     End If
     Application.CellDragAndDrop = true
     Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I suppose that looks better. :) (Note that there needs to be a "Screen Updating=True" before the Exit Sub or else it freezes the screen indefinitely). I organised it the way I did so that as little as possible happened before the "Exit Sub" to minimise any delay after double clicking otherwise.

Comment: Yes, of course, I forgot! I've just edited the code to insert a 'screenupdating=true'. And yes, I understand the reason, but well organized code will help you a lot if you ever need to read it in the future (I've had some bad experiences).

Comment: Does this answer the question?  I am keen to disable the double click navigation but I am unsure how this tells me how to do that...

Comment: @Jerry. No this does not answer the question.